# mod_rewrite and the regex OR condition

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Does the **OR** condition work in mod_rewrite? My rule is throwing an internal server error:

```
RewriteRule ^(Bob|Sam|Arnold|Brian).htm$ http://newdomain.net/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Alternatively, is there a better rewriting system which can load a list of possible page names to rewrite? Or perhaps an inverse way to do this - regex to select which pages NOT to rewrite? (Say, not `index`, `abbreviations`, or `contact`).

Comment: `OR` does work in mod_rewrite, but normally they are used in a `RewriteCond` for the `RewriteRule`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: As of 500 error - what does `error.log` tell about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably getting the 500 server error because you have a space before the `L` flag. Apache isn't all that clever about parsing directives and their parameters, so when apache see's a space, it assumes the beginning/end of parameters. So `[R=301,` and `L]` end up being interpreted as 2 different parameters, and they're not valid separately like that.

The "OR" functionality is fine.

```
RewriteRule ^(Bob|Sam|Arnold|Brian)\.htm$ http://newdomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can do negative matches using a `?!` type of group:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index|abbreviations|contact)(.*)\.htm$ http://newdomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would handle the OR.  You'll need to separate them into `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(Bob|Sam|Arnold|Brian).htm$ [OR]
# Another RewriteCond would go here as the "OR" like:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index|abbreviations|contact) # ! = "not"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.net/$1 [R=301, L]
```

As far as being able to "load a list of possible page names to rewrite," I don't know of any way to do that other than listing them manually with `mod_rewrite`.  I know [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html), for example, supposedly has more in depth features involving that.